# An ItemTemplate Containing A Combobox - How Do I Bind To The SelectedValue?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Imagine your working on a UI for an Wedding Planner app.  You'll have a list of guests and you want to display their name on the screen next to a combobox containing values of 'Will Attend' / 'Maybe' / 'No'.

I've tried to something just that....I have a collection of items inside a view model (the guests).  For each of those items I want to display a Label and a ComboBox.  Each ComboBox has the same values in the drop down (the possible responses).

I've created an ItemTemplate that contains a label and a combobox.  I bind it to my collection of guests and it works as expected.  I'm using ancestor binding so that the ComboBox's ItemsSource is bound to the list of possible responses.  That works great.

What I'm struggling with is how to bind the SelectedItem to get the values the user selects?  I want to have a collection of selected values on the ViewModel somehow, but I'm having a lot of trouble finding the correct words to describe this / search for it.

Can anyone help me?  Am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may create an enum for the attendance state and add an `Attendance` property to your Guest class:

```
public enum Attendance
{
    Yes,
    No,
    Maybe
}

public class Guest
{
    ...
    public Attendance Attendance { get; set; } // raise PropertyChanged event if necessary
}
```

Now you could set the `Tag` property of the ComboBox items to the appropriate enum value and bind the `SelectedValue` property:

```
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding Attendance}" SelectedValuePath="Tag">
            <TextBlock Tag="Yes">Will Attend</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Tag="No">Won't Attend</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Tag="Maybe">May Attend</TextBlock>
        </ComboBox>
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```